# X -config Leaves a Blank Screen

Tags: linux, xorg, slackware

In Slackware, when I use the command "Xorg -configure" to setup the X server, I get the following:

```
(EE) Failed to load module "vmwgfx" (module does not exist, 0).
(EE) vmware: Please ignore the above warnings about not being able to load module/driver vmwgfx (???)
(EE) vmware: unexpected failure while loading the "vmlegacy" driver. Giving up.
(EE) LoadModule: Module xgi does not have a xgi ModuleData data object.
(EE) Failed to load module "xgi" (invalid module, 0)
(++) Using config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d".
```

Because of this, when I test the Xserver, all I get is a blank screen. What can I do to fix this? I'm running a Gateway NV57H laptop with an intel graphics card.

**update**

Problem fixed. While I wasn't able to test the X server from the commandline, I was able to make my distro *restart* into the x server. This problem has now been solved.

Comment: I had this issue a couple of days ago. I then uninstalled all unneeded xorg video drivers and after that it worked...

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: I don't know about slackware, I was using pacman which comes with arch linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're testing the X server by just running Xorg, then a blank screen is the expected result on current Xorg versions - it stays black until programs connect and tell it to draw something.   For standalone testing, you probably want to specify the `-retro` flag to restore the old gray backdrop and default X cursor.